# Visual Code on Windows Client shows stale data from Remote Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-access

After trying to connect to my Desktop at work last night and failing due to network issues, this morning when using Visual Code SSH, the files inside Visual Code are old files (I can tell because if I go to the same folder using terminal ssh, I see the files are different).  IOW, it seems like Visual Code is showing me an older version of the files.  I tried removing the VC server cache on the desktop but still seeing the same issue.  Has anyone seen this?

My setup:

Client: Windows 10 pro running Visual Code with the remote SSH extension

Server: Ubuntu 16.04 (which also has Visual Code installed)

Please note, till Yesterday, the setup was working fine.  I could edit files on the remote from the local VS and compile on the remote host.  But Today, the files that I see on Visual Studio do not correspond to those in the same folder on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be false alarm.  The problem was that Visual Code was pointing to the wrong tree.